# Multiple updates at once via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track at the moment:

Made a little thing so an admin can edit people's schedules. Right now he clicks on a row and all the schedules become editable. If he changes values in a row I'm catching it with

```
$('.selector').change(function() { // this happens to be a <select> dropdown. I guess technically this is the <option> inside of the select.
    var updates = new Array(); // an array of all the updates
    var classList = $(this).attr('id').split(/\s+\); // the id of a <select> would be something like "12 monday start" meaning the user_id, day_of_week, start/end time. Just converting it to an array here.
    classList.push($(this).val()); // the time it has been changed to
    updates.push(classList); // add the singular time update to the overall array
    $('.save_schedule').click(function() {
        // here I would iterate through all of the arrays in updates and do some sort of ajax call, correct?
    });
});
```

Just want to make sure that I'm on the right track before I go any further and have to potentially rewrite things.

Thanks

My HTML since it has been requested: https://gist.github.com/2435293

Comment: have you run the code? getting the output you expected? then you are on **right track**..

Comment: I haven't actually gotten to the point where it's sending the ajax request, since I've never used ajax before. The objects look correct, but I haven't yet tried the sending requests.

Comment: This sounds more like a database update_all rather than an ajax update_all question.  Sending an array of ids is rather simple, updating multi rows would depend on your database setup.  Are you using an ORM or just a raw query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your HTML looks somehow like this

```
<select id="12 monday start" class="selector">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="12 monday end" class="selector">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="button" class="save_schedule" value="save" />
```

your javascript could look like this

```
$('.save_schedule').click(function() {

    var arr = new Array();
    $('.selector').each(function() {

        arr.push($(this).attr('id').split(/\s+/));
        arr.push($(":selected", this).val())
    });

    alert(arr);
    // ajax call here
});
```

[see jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2pJet/3/)

Comment: This is way easier than what I was doing - thanks for that. But how should I account for multiple changes on the same user's schedule at once? I have an overall save button instead of one per each select.

Comment: This works well for me, but now I have another problem: when I grab all the values for a certain row I'm creating a new array for each <select>. From there, I add all of those arrays into another array. That second array is the one I'm using in my ajax data field, but it's not updating anything. Any suggestions? http://pastebin.com/8PXyAkzb what I have at the moment. It was working earlier with my way-too-complex code, but something is breaking now.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to implement this:

OPTION 1 - draft saving

Each time the user edits a row, you make an AJAX call to temporary save his changes (add a database column `draft` to distinct drafts from real changes).

You should move the `click` handler outside the `change` handler:

```
$('.selector').change(function() {
    ... 
});
$('.save_schedule').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

In the `change` handler, `$(this)` points to the current tag `select`.
To get the selected value, you can use `$(this).val()`.

To avoid splitting the select id attribute to get all the elements you need, you can use custom attributes:

```
<select data-user-id="12" data-day="monday" data-time="start">...</select>
```

Then, in your `change` handler, you can use the `attr` method to get their values.

```
var user_id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
var day = $(this).attr('data-day');
var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
```

Now, you can make an ajax call to store the changes as `draft`.

When the user clicks on `save_schedule`, make a final ajax call to update the status of the drafts and set it to permanent.

OPTION 2 - simple save, form serializing

All changes are saved only when the user clicks on save button.

I would recommend to keep all the data in HTML tags and not in Javascript. (for reasons like: What happens if the user edits twice a schedule? Are the changes pushed again in the array?).

You could hide the inputs/selects when they are not editable and you won't need to treat the `change` event anymore.

When the user clicks on `save_schedule`, you can use a function like `$(form).serialize()` to gather all the data from your inputs (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and make an AJAX call to save your changes.